# How to compare fields from two CSV files with an arithmetic condition?

Tags: python, csv

I have two csv files. The first file contains names of all countries with their capital cities,

CSV 1:

```
   Capital       Country     Country Code
   Budapest      Hungary     HUN 
   Rome          Italy       ITA
   Dublin        Ireland     IRL
   Paris         France      FRA
   Berlin        Germany     DEU
   .
   .
   .
```

CSV 2:

Second CSV file contains trip details of a bus,

```
 Trip City     Trip Country    No. of pax
 Budapest         HUN            24 
 Paris            FRA            36 
 Munich           DEU            9 
 Florence         ITA            5 
 Milan            ITA            25 
 Rome             ITA            2
 Rome             ITA            45
```

I would like to add a new column df["Touism visit"] with the values of no of pax, if the Trip City (from CSV 2) is a capital of a country (from CSV 1) and if the number of pax is more than 10.

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: what are you looking to do? You say you want to add a column to only those cities which are in csv 1 and have no. of pax > 10, but you can't add a new column to only some rows. Do you want a specific value in that column

Comment: @GhilasBELHADJ i did ! but the output was not correct and so i didnt post it here

Comment: @Stael i would like to obtain the values of "no of pax" in the df["tourism visit"] column. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df2['tourism'] = 0
df2.loc[df2['Trip City'].isin(df1['Capital']) & (df2['No. of pax'] > 10), 'tourism'] = df2.loc[df2['Trip City'].isin(df1['Capital'])& (df2['No. of pax'] > 10), 'No. of pax']
```

I get :

```
  Trip_City Trip_Country  No._of_pax  tourism
0  Budapest          HUN          24       24
1     Paris          FRA          36       36
2    Munich          DEU           9        0
3  Florence          ITA           5        0
4     Milan          ITA          25        0
5      Rome          ITA           2        0
6      Rome          ITA          45       45
```

(I had to add _s to get `pd.read_clipboard()` to work properly)

Comment: just realised i forgot the >10 - give me a sec

Comment: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). :(

Comment: @Iris it works for me - are you sure you haven't moved any brackets around? or replaced & with `and` or anything like that?

Answer (score 1):

If you  filter your second dataframe to only the values `> 10`, you could merge and sum as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Capital': ['Budapest', 'Rome', 'Dublin', 'Paris',
                                'Berlin'],
                    'Country': ['Hungary', 'Italy', 'Ireland', 'France',
                                'Germany'],
                    'Country Code': ['HUN', 'ITA', 'IRL', 'FRA', 'DEU']
                    })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Trip City': ['Budapest', 'Paris', 'Munich', 'Florence',
                                  'Milan', 'Rome', 'Rome'],
                    'Trip Country': ['HUN', 'FRA', 'DEU', 'ITA', 'ITA',
                                     'ITA', 'ITA'],
                    'No. of pax': [24, 36, 9, 5, 25, 2, 45]
                    })

df2 = df2[df2['No. of pax'] > 10]

combined = df1.merge(df2,
                     left_on=['Capital', 'Country Code'],
                     right_on=['Trip City', 'Trip Country'],
                     how='left').groupby(['Capital', 'Country Code'],
                                         sort=False,
                                         as_index=False)['No. of pax'].sum()

print combined
```

This prints:

```
    Capital Country Code  No. of pax
0  Budapest          HUN        24.0
1      Rome          ITA        45.0
2    Dublin          IRL         NaN
3     Paris          FRA        36.0
4    Berlin          DEU         NaN
```

Comment: This is probably quicker than mine, but it cuts out non-capitals from the data. I don't know if that's what the OP wants or not, just worth saying.

Comment: actually this doesn't work because you merge on trip country == country code but Hungary != HUN

Comment: @Stael yes it does - `Trip Country` in CSV2 is the same as `Country Code` in CSV1. Try it out.

Comment: but I don't get your answer when I copy/paste it into a jupyter notebook - i get budapest - Hun - 64.0

Comment: for some reason in your example you have budapest in twice, which I don't understand, which also raises the question of why you're grouping and summing, which wasn't in the question.

Comment: @Stael apologies, I was correcting some unclear indentation and accidentally copied across a further version I was testing. I have edited this back so the values match. The reason for merging and summing is that I interpreted the question as seeking the total number of visitors to each capital city.

Comment: no worries, I was just confused when I copy/pasted it and didn't get the answer you get! Sorry, I have been really on your case about a perfectly good answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

this might also help,

import the dfs

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("CSV1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("CSV2.csv")

make a dictionary out of the pandas Series 
my_dict=dict(zip((df1["Country_Code"]),(df1["Capital"])))
```

define a function that test your conditions (note i used `np.logical_and()` to combine the conditions. A normal `and`

```
def isTourism(country_code,trip_city,No_of_pax):
   if np.logical_and((my_dict[country_code]==trip_city),(No_of_pax >= 10)): 
       return "Yes" 
   else:
       return "No
```

call function with `map`

```
df2["Tourism"] = list(map(isTourism,df2["Trip Country"],df2["Trip City"], df2["No. Of pax"]))

print(df2)

    Trip City   Trip Country    No. Of pax  Tourism
0   Budapest    HUN               24        Yes
1   Paris       FRA               36        Yes
2   Munich      DEU               9         No
3   Florence    ITA               5         No
4   Milan       ITA               25        No
5   Rome        ITA               2         No
6   Rome        ITA               45        Yes
```

Comment: yay my first post :)

Comment: thank you for your answer! keep going ! Good luck! ^^